# How do I load jquery from below code snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried using ken wheelers slick slider and after trying it, it seems nothing is working only some static content displays, going through online forums i found out that the problem is that jquery is not loaded, so how do i load jquery from below code? Thanks in advance!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="fade">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Joachim-Mpanda/Desktop/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function() {
      $('.fade').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 700,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you open console and see if there is an error?

Comment: Look closely at:     <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Joachim-Mpanda/Desktop/script.js"></script>


I am not saying that is your problem - but it's likely one of your problems.

There are a few issues with it, but I recommend you change to relative reference:  <script src="./..."> </script>

Are you familiar with Chome's devTools - check out the console error messages.

Comment: i opened dev tools and here is an error i got from the console                    Script.js:1Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
slick.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).load`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.fade').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 700,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows:false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="fade">
         <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried but nothing worked, i opened dev tools and here is an error i got from the console                                                                                               
Script.js:1Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
slick.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: That's a different issue.  You can try downloading the scripts and loading them from the file system if you're having network issues. Or try pasting the path into the address bar of your browser to make sure you can access those files.